# Swift Countdown from game end + 1 hour

Tags: swift, timer, nsdate

I am trying to create a timer between games, so that after a user loses a life they must wait 5min until they can play again. However I am not sure what the best way to do this is.

I need it also to be safe against the user just editing their time in Settings.

What is the best way to achieve this?

At the moment I am going through the process of setting an NSDate() object in the keychain:

```
let date = NSDate()
```

and then using this to get the values:

```
let date = gameActions["EndFight"] as! NSDate
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components([ .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: date)
        let Hour = components.hour
        let Minute = components.minute

        print("Hour: \(Hour)")
        print("Mins: \(Minute)")
```

However **Hour** always returns as **1**. After looking around a lot it occurred to me that I might be going about this a whole wrong way.

I was then going to reverse this [Swift Timer](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swift/swift-timer-tutorial-create-a-counter-timer-application-using-nstimer/) tutorial to count down backwards..

Is this the right track?

Main question for clarification:

**How would I be able to determine if 5 mins has passed since the last game fight?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is by utilizing timestamps on your backend at UTC 0. You cannot safeguard against a user changing the time on their phone, so don't rely on any timestamps from there.

If you want to prevent a user from having access to a feature for *x* amount of time, then log their activity on the backend.

Then to compare between two dates, try this:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let dateComponenets = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.Minute, fromDate: serverActivityLogDate, toDate: serverCurrentDate, options: [])
let minutes = dateComponenets.minute
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I do get this error: Type 'NSCalendarUnit' has no member 'CalendarUnitSecond' - do you think you can help with this?

Comment: Sorry about that. Was a bit of older code. I've update the answer.